# Centralized formatting settings with oomph

Tags: eclipse, share, formatter, centralized, oomph

I got a task about replacing `Workspace Mechanic` in Eclipse since there are no commits since 2014 and sometimes it doesn't work without reason.

I could create and configure a `installation.setup` file successfully on my local machine with some code clean-up formatting and save actions preferences which are loaded each start automatically. :)

The last step is to centralize the setup-file on a network drive.

Workspace mechanics enables to configue a directory with the settingfiles inside.

[image]

`Oomph` may not support the way I thougt. There is a way to synchronize to [Eclipse.org](http://Eclipse.org) but we want to keep the information inside the company due to policy reason.

[image]

Is there any way to store a central (Oomph) setup-file which synchronizes to each Eclipse client at start up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse plugin yatta. It "manages your Eclipse setups – for yourself, your team, or within the community.". Of course, you can simply share the Preferences - other options it provides is share repos and projects.

https://www.yatta.de/profiles/help

With yatta you will create an Eclipse Installer, that can be installed on different clients. The clients will receive Updates of the 'master-settings' and there is the option to fork as well. Settings will be not be saved in local network but in the clould. From scratch, your profile will be private, you can share it with single persons, a group (*@yourcompany.com) or you can share it to public as well.

While Yatta is a handy to use plugin, it is based on Oomph, which is the complex way (you have several 'ontop' configurations for product, project, installation & workspace). In fact, both can do what you want.